# removeListing() method in my class is throwing a null pointer exception

Tags: java, arrays, exception, nullpointerexception

This is my library class which creates a "library" of type Book called listings. I tried to create a removeListing() function, but when I call it on my array named listings, I get a null pointer exception at the first if statement in the removeListing() method.

I checked the other question on what a nullpointerexception is but I'm still not sure why my specific if statement is tossing one. Thank you for the help!

```
class Library {
private Book[] listings;
// Contains all books in the library
// Not guaranteed that every location is a valid book

private int totalListings;
// Represents the total number of books in the library

private static final int DEFAULT_SIZE = 8;
// Default size the library is set to

public Library()
{
    listings = new Book[DEFAULT_SIZE];
}
// Default and only constructor
// Create a library with a capacity of DEFAULT_SIZE

public boolean addListing(String t, String a, int y)
{
        if (totalListings < DEFAULT_SIZE) //this may also be written as if(totalListings < DEFAULT_SIZE)
        {
            System.out.println("Your book " + t + ", written by " + a + ", on " 
                    + y + " was added to the library.");
            Object[] newObj = appendValue(listings, t, a, y);
            totalListings++; 
            return true;          
        }
        else{
            System.out.println("There was no more room in the library.");
            return false;
        }
}

private Object[] appendValue(Book[] listings, String t, String a, int y) {

ArrayList<Object> temp = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(listings));
temp.add(new Book(t, a, y));
return temp.toArray();
  }
// Try to add a book
// Return true if the book can be added
// If there are no spots left return false and don't add the book

public void removeListing(String title, String author, int year){
    for(int i=0; i<listings.length; i++){
        if(listings[i].getTitle().equals(title)){
            if(listings[i].getAuthor().equals(author)){
                if(listings[i].getYear() == year){
                    System.out.println("Found your book.");
                }
            }
        }
    } 
}
```

Comment: Well your comment does state "Not guaranteed that every location is a valid book", so why not check first?

Answer (score 2):

In your constructor, you are initializing listings with Book[] of size 8, but not populating with any values.

```
listings = new Book[DEFAULT_SIZE];
```

I have added a method getBooksDetails() for your understanding which prints the details of Book[].

```
public void getBooksDetails(){
    System.out.println("Default size of listings-" + listings.length);
    System.out.println("Occupied size of listings-" + totalListings);

    for (int i = 0; i < listings.length; i++) {
        System.out.println(listings[i]);
    }
}
```

If you call this method from main(), you can see following output in console.

```
public static void main(String... args){
    Library library = new Library();
    library.getBooksDetails();
}
```

**Output**

> Default size of listings-8
>
> Occupied size of listings-0
>
> null
>
> null
>
> null
>
> null
>
> null
>
> null
>
> null
>
> null

When you call Library constructor, your listings will be having 8 null elements. Hence will get nullpointer exception if you call removeListing().
You should

- call addListing() to add the books to listings.
- instead of calling appendValue from addListing(), add Book object to listings inside addListing() only as follows,

  listings[totalListings++] = new Book(t, a, y);
- Use totalListings in for loop of removeListing() since you increment the value of same in addListing() method.

Answer (score 0):

You are getting a NullPointerException because `listings[i].getTitle()` is null. The title of the listing is null, because you never actually set the title for any of the 8 books in `listings`.

To quickly fix the NullPointerException, change your if statement to the following:

```
if(title.equals(listings[i].getTitle())) {
    ...
}
```

This will return false when `listings[i]` does not have a title.

To fix the overall program, there is a bug in your `appendValue` function. You never actually modify `listings`. It should look something like this:

```
private void appendValue(Book[] listings, String t, String a, int y) {
    listings[totalListings] = new Book(t, a, y);
}
```